# Erro ao tentar inserir com o PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando executar essa função em php:

```
$insert = $con ->prepare("INSERT INTO conta (conta, senha, email, acesso) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $insert ->bind_param("sssi", $usuario->getConta(), md5($usuario->getSenha()), $usuario->getEmail, 1);

        $insert ->execute();
```

Porem quando eu uso a seguinte função:

```
$insert = $con ->prepare("INSERT INTO conta (conta, senha, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        $insert ->bind_param("sss", $usuario->getConta(), md5($usuario->getSenha()), $usuario->getEmail);

        $insert ->execute();
```

Ele funciona mas quando tento inserir esse número inteiro no final ele não executa e mostra a seguinte mensagem de erro:
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 5 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\payment\lib\php\usuario.php on line 11

Já não sei mas o que fazer.

No meu banco todos são varchar menos o ultimo que é um int (11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente está utilizando [**MySQLi**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php), não [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php), não coisas distintas e que pode confundir quem venha responder, uma vez que possuem grandes diferenças. *Se quer dizer que está utilizando programação orientada a objeto seria `POO` ou `OO`, mas não PDO*.

Agora vamos ao problema:

O [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (ou [$mysqli_stmt->bind_param](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)) aceita variáveis por referencia, mas não aceita string diretamente nela.

```
$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO conta (conta, senha, email, acesso) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

// Pode definir antes do bind_param:
//$numero = 1;

$insert ->bind_param("sssi",
    $conta,
    $senha,
    $email,
    $numero
);

// Pode definir depois do bind_param, mas antes do execute:
$numero = 1;

$senha = md5( $usuario->getSenha() );
$email = $usuario->getEmail();
$conta = $usuario->getConta();

$insert ->execute();
```

Agora o `1` está sendo passado pelo `$numero`, o valor do o `$numero` pode deve ser definido antes do `execute();`, mas não necessariamente antes do `bind_param`.

O primeiro argumento do `bind_param`, o "`sssi`", é determinado da seguinte maneira:

```
+-------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Letra |          Descricao            |                Exemplo                 |
+-------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| i     | Define variável como Inteiro  | INT, TIMESTAMP, BIT...                 |
| s     | Define variável como String   | CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT, DATETIME, JSON... |
| d     | Define variável como Double   | DOUBLE, FLOAT, DECIMAL...              |
| b     | Define variável como Blob     | BLOB, BINARY...                        |
+-------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

A definição deve ser exatamente na ordem que está na `query` com os parâmetros, caso defina `si` deve informar uma variável sendo `$string, $int`.

> Não recomendo o uso do MD5 e nem SHA1 para senhas. Utilize em seu lugar o [BCrypt](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) que está incluindo já no PHP nas funções de [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php) se realmente quiser diferentes sistemas de proteções de senhas existe o `Libsodium` (que suporta o `SCrypt` e também o `Argon2`), o [Libsodium já está disponível](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php), utilizando o `\Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str()`, [isso será incluído "já de fabrica" no PHP 7.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/libsodium).

Comment: Inkeliz(+1), adiciona na sua resposta a tabelinha de especificação de tipo dessa url: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
i  corresponde a uma variável de tipo inteiro
d  corresponde a uma variável de tipo double
s  corresponde a uma variável de tipo string
b  corresponde a uma variável que contém dados para um blob e enviará em pacotes

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre adicionei isto.